# How to check whether the id of RadGrid EditColumn is valid or not in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using the following code in asp(code is written in javascript)

```
function Check_Option_IntRate() 
{
   debugger;

   for (var i=100; i<=110; i++)
   {
       var temp1='ctl00_MainContent_radgrd_InvPur_ctl00_ct'+i+'_rdo_intrev';

       if (document.getElementById(temp1))
       {
           var Rd_IntId= document.getElementById('temp1').id;
           if (document.getElementById('temp1').checked == true) {
              document.getElementById('call5').style.display = "Block";
              document.getElementById('call6').style.display = "Block";
       }
       else {
            document.getElementById('call5').style.display = "None";
            document.getElementById('call6').style.display = "None";
       }
   }
}
return false;
```

here rdo_intrev is radio button. used as asp control. This is being declared as a editcolum in RadGrid. So in every row of the radgrid the asp generatted id will change. Thats why i have used for loop here(**ctl00_MainContent_radgrd_InvPur_ctl00_ct'+i+'_rdo_intrev**). I want to check whether the control id is valid or not. But  **if (document.getElementById(temp1))** results null only.

How can i check that. Is there any better way to solve this problem.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In asp controls we set `clientIdMode = "static"` so that Id will be same on the client side. So you can check this RadGrid if this option is available then set it to `static` so you can get control by same id on the server side.

Comment: Am using 3.5 version of ASP.net. ClientIdMode is not available. How can i use that..

Comment: Other way is that you can use scriptlets to get client id. e.g `<%= rdo_intrev.ClientID%>`. Using this you can get client id for your control.

Comment: I have used $find('[id$="rdo_intrev"]') and $find('<%= rdo_intrev.ClientID%>') already. But it throws error when build. "rdo_intrev is not declared". But it is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code

```
  if (temp1)
           {
             var first=temp1+"_0";
            if (first.checked == true) {
                  document.getElementById('call5').style.display = "Block";
                  document.getElementById('call6').style.display = "Block";
           }
           else {
                document.getElementById('call5').style.display = "None";
                document.getElementById('call6').style.display = "None";
           }
```

Hope this will work.